# adding a column to a pandas dataframe using a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add columns to an existing dataframe based on a dictionary. If my dataframe looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
column_names=['name','surname','age']
lfa=[("tom","jones",44),("elvis","prestley",50),("jim","reeves",30)]
lfa=pd.DataFrame(lfa,columns=column_names)
lfa
```

and my dictionary looks like:

```
new_cols= {"adj1":"adjustment1","adj2":"adjustment2"}
```

then, I am trying to get a  dataframe that looks like:

```
column_names=['name','surname','age','adj1','adj2']
lfa=[("tom","jones",44,"adjustment1","adjustment2"), 
("elvis","prestley",50,"adjustment1","adjustment2"), 
("jim","reeves",30,"adjustment1","adjustment2")]
lfa=pd.DataFrame(lfa,columns=column_names)
lfa
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with unpack dict by `**`:

```
df = lfa.assign(**new_cols)
print (df)
    name   surname  age         adj1         adj2
0    tom     jones   44  adjustment1  adjustment2
1  elvis  prestley   50  adjustment1  adjustment2
2    jim    reeves   30  adjustment1  adjustment2
```

Or [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = lfa.join(pd.DataFrame(new_cols, index=lfa.index))
print (df)
    name   surname  age         adj1         adj2
0    tom     jones   44  adjustment1  adjustment2
1  elvis  prestley   50  adjustment1  adjustment2
2    jim    reeves   30  adjustment1  adjustment2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by:-

```
lfa[list(new_cols.keys())]=new_cols.values()

print(lfa)
    name    surname     age     adj1        adj2
0   tom     jones       44  adjustment1     adjustment2
1   elvis   prestley    50  adjustment1     adjustment2
2   jim     reeves      30  adjustment1     adjustment2
```

Comment: please use `df.assign()` as it is the most efficient way to add the columns in this case. However, your trick works as well

Comment: @jezrael already mentioned  that in his answer so I come up with this method

Answer (score 1):

One way could be using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
In [533]: df = pd.concat([lfa, pd.DataFrame(new_cols, index=lfa.index)], 1)

In [534]: df
Out[534]: 
    name   surname  age         adj1         adj2
0    tom     jones   44  adjustment1  adjustment2
1  elvis  prestley   50  adjustment1  adjustment2
2    jim    reeves   30  adjustment1  adjustment2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a loop on dictionary key-value pairs and add them to you dataframe.

```
for key,value in new_cols.items():
    lfa[key] = value
```